# Как определить, входит ли точка gps в определенный маршрут

Tags: алгоритм, gps, навигация

У меня есть  набор gps координат, которые описывают собой определенный маршрут (каждая точка это широта и долгота). Мне нужно понять, находиться ли мое устройство в данный момент на таком маршруте с учетом погрешности в 10 метров. Устройство определяет где оно находится также по широте и долготе

Answer (score 0):

В простом случае у вас есть набор отрезков, соединяющий точки маршрута [Pi,Pi+1], 0<i<N, N - к-во точек маршрута. Далее берете точку и применяете по очереди к отрезкам функцию определения расстояния от точки до отрезка, например [тут есть код на C++](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?194400-Distance-between-point-and-line-segment).

В общем случае необходимо сделать экстраполяцию маршрута с точностью до 2.5 метров.

Answer (score 0):

С учётом заданной погрешности - задача сложная.
Чтобы решить её, требуется:

1. Представить данные маршрута в виде, удобном для вычисления его точек с шагом 1м.
   Например, хранить коэффициенты сплайна между точками маршрута.
2. Обеспечить требуемую точность для координаты устройства. Если устройство неподвижно, то усреднить данные измерений. Если в движении - оценить параметры линейной модели движения и получить среднюю координату.
3. Если точность данных достаточна, то привязка - дело нехитрое. Расстояние между двумя точками известно, а возможных точек маршрута немного, даже при интерполяции с шагом 1 м.